# Joomla 1.7: wysiwyg editor doesn't work

Tags: joomla, tinymce

Joomla version: 1.7

Pluign "Editor - TinyMCE" enabled

But editor doesn't work

In global config choosed "TinyMce"

In configuration.php:   public $editor = 'tinymce';

It is works, if link it directly to some field and tell system concrete editor:

```
$editor = &JFactory::getEditor('tinymce');
echo $editor->display( 'name_field', 'text', '700', '400', '', '', true);
```

But this display empty textarea without editor:

```
editor = &JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display( 'name_field', 'text', '700', '400', '', '', true);
```

And by default in articles, etc. it is empty

None of core files haven't been changed

The system always loads plugin/editors/none , but in global config choosed tinymce

Any suggestions, why this happens?

**UPD.** Solved.

I just disabled none & codemirror plugins. Now tinymce works fine!

Comment: +1 you should post your solution as anser and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled none & codemirror plugins. Now tinymce works fine!